# Call to invokeStaticMethod can't be resolved?

Tags: clojure

I've written a rather primitive test program (I am writing a wrapper around LWJGL's OpenGL classes for mostly aesthetic reasons, and I decided to bring multi-threading in there because I actually never wrote a concurrent program before). <s>When the program finishes, I always get the warning</s>

I actually get the warning before the program enters the main function. Sorry for the confusion (I think this may not be my program at all, but rather something in clojure itself):

```
Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_PATH:1 - call to invokeStaticMethod can't be resolved.
```

I don't get any warnings during compilation though, which I find rather strange. Anyway, here is the program:

```
(ns opengltuts.core
  (:import (org.lwjgl.opengl GL11 Display))
  (:use opengltuts.opengl)) ;my wrapper

(def world-state (ref {:running true :color [1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0]}))

(defn render-world [state]
  (apply glClearColor (:color state))
  (glClear GL11/GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
  (Display/update))

(defn render []
  (Display/create)
  (loop []
    (let [world @world-state]
      (when (:running world)
        (do (render-world world)
          (recur)))))
  (Display/destroy))

(defn -main []
  ; without the annotation, I get a warning here too.
  (let [render-thread (doto (Thread. ^Runnable render) (.start))]
    (Thread/sleep 3000)
    (dosync (commute world-state assoc :color [0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0]))
    (Thread/sleep 3000)
    (dosync (commute world-state assoc :running false))
    (.join render-thread)))
```

This probably isn't too idiomatic (I heard that in Clojure you normally don't start threads with `new Thread`, but rather with Agents or something, but I don't fully grasp how that works yet), but I guess for such a short program that doesn't matter.

Comment: If you need a simple thread, you can use `future` instead of agent. i.e. `(future (render))`. Also, `Thread/sleep` is ok, see http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/future

Comment: Are you certain the warning isn't coming from `opengltuts.opengl`? Somewhere, you are calling an overloaded static method and it can't resolve the exact invocation. Regarding it occurring at runtime, are you generating code at runtime?

Comment: @noahz No I'm not generating code. And this only happens at the end of the program, when I'm already long done calling opengl functions.

Also, using a future for this is kinda weird. It does save me some dots, but now I need this weird call to (shutdown-agents) at the end because clojure can't figure out when it's time to quit anymore. Oh and of course dereferencing a nil value to cause a side effect doesn't sit right with me either.

I was mistaken about the timing - I get the warning before I'm entering the main function.

Comment: Regarding `shutdown-agents` - that's Java Executor API, not Clojure. Are you using ahead of time compilation?

Comment: Ahead of time compilation? I'm running `lein compile` before `lein run` if that's what you mean (precisely _because_ I try to avoid unnecessary reflection as long as it can be done without much of a hassle).

Comment: Check under `target/classes/` (if it exists after you compile). Unless your namespace has `gen-class` the source file does not get aot compiled. http://clojure.org/compilation

Answer (score 0):

Your Clojure source code is being loaded and compiled at runtime (see http://clojure.org/compilation), which is why you don't see the reflection warning until program execution.

It is difficult to determine where you're making a reflective call against a static method, so here are steps I recommend:

1. Add `(:gen-class)` to your `(ns)` declaration
2. Add `(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)` or `(binding [*warn-on-reflection* true] body)` where you suspect the reflective call is occurring.

Comment: I compile with the leiningen project setting :warn-on-reflection. I get reflection warnings for all my modules, and none of them cause one during compilation.

Comment: After you run `lein compile` what do you see under `target/classes/`?

Comment: opengltuts-> a bunch of classes with ns$function.class names. As well as 

`core__init.class`
`core$loading__4784__auto__.class `
`core$_main$fn__155.class`
`core$_main$fn__157.class`

Comment: Ok, that's all I got. Good luck!